# ParametricPlot with 2 variables

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I want to try plotting this:
[image]

As you can see the first axis is v  and the second is just dependent of the angle of $\Phi$ .

The function is

```
plot = ParametricPlot[
  141.20^2/(16 π) (Abs[Subscript[I, 0]]^2 + 
 4 Abs[Subscript[I, 1]]^2 *Cos[Φ]^2 + 
 Abs[Subscript[I, 2]]^2 + 
 2*Cos[2 Φ]*
  Re[Subscript[I, 0] Conjugate[Subscript[I, 2]]]),
 {Φ,0, π/2}, {v, 0, 10}]
```

and looks like this $w=141,20^2(\lvert{I_0}\rvert+4 \lvert{I_1}\rvert*cos^2(\Phi)+\lvert{I_2}^2\lvert+2 cos(2\Phi)*\Re{(I_0 I_2^*)})$

Before that I have defined `I_0, I_1 and I_2`. They are dependent from the variable v. and

```
α = 45/180 π

Subscript[I, 0] = 
NIntegrate[
Sqrt[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] (1 + Cos[θ]) BesselJ[
0, (v Sin[θ])/Sin[α]], {θ, 0, α}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 20]


Subscript[I, 1] = 
NIntegrate[
Sqrt[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ]^2 BesselJ[
1, (v Sin[θ])/Sin[α]] , {θ, 0, α}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 20]

Subscript[I, 2] = NIntegrate[
Sqrt[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ] (1 - Cos[θ]) BesselJ[
2, (v Sin[θ])/Sin[α]] , {θ, 0, α}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 20]
```

What is wrong with my code?

Can I use `Contours -> {}` and `ContourLabels -> All` with  `ParametricPlot` aswell, or is it just for `ContourPlot`?

There is a paper focusing on this problem:http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/29/032/29032386.pdf
The Intensities `I_0,1,2`are on page 211 of the paper and is page 35 of the pdf, the plots are on page 218 of this paper and are pdf-page 42.

Comment: I think you want `ContourPlot` rather than `ParametricPlot`. What are the expressions for `I_0`, `I_1`, and `I_2`? What is the y-axis (is it Phi?). Also, don't use subscripts.

Comment: I used ParametricPlot because I want something like a unit circle. There isnt really a y-axis, just the angles.

Comment: So is `w` the variable corresponding to the y-axis then? In other words, is $\tan(\Phi) = w/v$? Or is $w$ the "$z$" value, i.e. the values of the contours shown? Also, in order to be able to reproduce what you are doing, we need the expressions for the three `I`'s. Also note that `I` is a protected symbol (the complex unit) in Mathematica. It is a good idea to use lower-case symbols for variable names in Mathematica since built-in functions are all capitalized.

Comment: Better yet: can you link to the book/article from where you obtained this figure?

Comment: no w is not corresponding to y. Thats why the first circle in the middle has the value w=90 and the ''value of the y'' and v are almost 0

Comment: Right, okay. The fact that $w$ is the quantity corresponding to the values of the contours makes this much more easy to do with `ContourPlot`.

Comment: I linked an article above.ok how can I connect ContourPlot with the angles? If I try to plot it with ContourPlot mathematica wants to have the y-axis

Comment: Those expressions in the pdf are integral expressions that depend on `u` and `v`. You said that you had expressions that depended only on `v`. Can you please include the expressions that *you* are using in code form in your answer? You're likely to get more help if all the details are in copyable Mathematica form.

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to mention that in this problem u=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that what you want is a `ContourPlot`, with a *strong* caveat (see below). Your function is defined in polar coordinates, so in order to use `ContourPlot`, we need to transform to polar coordinates, as:

```
v -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
phi -> ArcTan[x, y]
```

Thus, replace any instance of `v` or `phi` in `w` with the corresponding expression in terms of of `x` and `y`, and call `ContourPlot` as

```
ContourPlot[ w
  , {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}
  , PlotRange -> All
  , ContourShading -> False
  , Contours -> {0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 10.0, 30.0, 50.0, 70.0, 90.0}
]
```

where

```
w = 141.20^2/(16*Pi)*(
  Abs[i0[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]^2 +
  Abs[i2[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]^2 + 
  4 Abs[i1[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]^2 Cos[ArcTan[y, x]] + 
  2 Cos[2 ArcTan[y, x]] Re[i0[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Conjugate[i2[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]]
 )
```

The next issue is that your expressions for `I_0`, `I_1`, and `I_2` are functions defined as numerical integrals, but the argument depend on `v`. So, we define these functions with `SetDelay` (`:=`) as

```
a = 45*Pi/180.;
Clear[i0, i1, i2]

i0[v_] :=  NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[Cos[t]] Sin[t] (1 + Cos[t]) BesselJ[0, (v Sin[t])/Sin[a]]
  , {t, 0, a}
  , PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 20]

i1[v_] :=  NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[Cos[t]] Sin[t]^2 BesselJ[1, (v Sin[t])/Sin[a]]
  , {t, 0, a}
  , PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 20]

i2[v_] :=  NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[Cos[t]] Sin[t] (1 - Cos[t]) BesselJ[2, (v Sin[t])/Sin[a]]
  , {t, 0, a}
  , PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 20]
```

Now, the problem here is that since these functions are defined in terms of integrals, the numerics of this problem cause it to be *extremely* slow. To see how long it will take, just try to find one contour with a restricted range via

```
ContourPlot[
  w
 , {y, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}
 , PlotRange -> All
 , ContourShading -> False
 , Contours -> {50.0}
]
```

This results in the image shown below, but it takes (on my machine) 45 seconds. Alternatively, you can evaluate the function on a fine-enough grid and use `ListContourPlot`. I did

```
points = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, w}, {x, 0.000001, 10.000001, 0.1}, {y, 0.000001, 10.000001, 0.1}]
   , 1]
```

(`Flatten` is necessary in order to turn make sure that `points` is a `List` of ordered triples.) This takes a good amount of time (3 minutes on my machine), but you only need to do it once. Then you can make the contour plot and play around with the formatting all you want without having to re-evaluate the function. (Note that we need to avoid `x = 0` in our parameterization of the function; hence the `0.000001`'s. You can extend this to negative values of `x` and `y` in obvious ways.) Then, we call

```
ListContourPlot[points
 , PlotRange -> All
 , ContourShading -> False
 , Contours -> {0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 10.0, 30.0, 50.0, 70.0, 90.0}]
```

resulting in the second figure below.

Another possible solution is to numerically integrate the `I` functions on a grid first, then create `InterpolatingFunctions` that can then be used in `ContourPlot`. The next step is to see if that works.

[image]

**Pedagogical Note**

The reason `ParametricPlot` is not the right answer here is that the correct format for that type of plot is

```
ParametricPlot[ {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1} ]
```

or, if you are in polar coordinates

```
ParametricPlot[ v[t]*{Cos[phi[t]], Sin[phi[t]]}, {t, 0, 1} ]
```

So, your idea of putting `w` in as the argument for `ParametricPlot` and trying to use two independent variables `v` and `phi` doesn't work for this type of plot.

Here, you could parameterize, say, `v` in terms of `phi` by solving

```
0.25 = w
```

for `v` to get the 0.25 contour of `w` (although there are multiple contours, so you would need to be careful), but you don't have any way of doing this analytically, and if you are doing things numerically, you should just `ContourPlot` anyway.

Comment: no this isnt it, because my u isnt v*tan[phi]. Its not Cartesian coordinates

Comment: thank you so much, this helps me alot. now I understand how to apply it here

Comment: sorry march I still have one question. I tied to reproduce it and everything worked fine till `ListContourPlot`. I'm getting a nothing there. just a plane koordinate. Then I tried it with `ContourPlot`. That solution was not quite right. The contours in the middle are not shown.Then I tried `Contourplot`with only the inner Contours. It gave me just one circle.

Comment: @donut. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Continuing with the *InterpolatingFunctions* suggested my March.

I was getting errors unless I set a finite *AccuracyGoal*.

I created data in the range -2 to 20 in steps of 0.1 (the range of interest is 0 to 10 so wanted data beyond this range) and then used that as input to the *Interpolation*.

```
i0[v_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Sqrt[Cos[t]] Sin[t] (1 + Cos[t]) BesselJ[0, (v Sin[t])/Sin[a]], {t,
     0, a}, PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 20, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 10^-8];

d0 = Map[{#, i0[#]} &, Range[-2, 20, 0.1]];

e0 = Interpolation[d0];
```

To test it I plotted the original function with the InterpolationFunction (here I used the Range -20 to 20).

```
Show[
 Plot[i0[v], {v, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}],
 Plot[e0[v], {v, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, White, Dashed}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I repeated these steps for i1 and i2 resulting in e1 and e2 InterpolationFunctions.

The contour plot using the numerical integration is painfully slow.

It took about 5 minutes to produce on my machine.

```
w = 141.20^2/(16*Pi)*(Abs[i0[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]^2 + 
    Abs[i2[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]^2 + 
    4 Abs[i1[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]^2 Cos[ArcTan[y, x]] + 
    2 Cos[2 ArcTan[y, x]] Re[
      i0[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Conjugate[i2[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]])
```

and then

```
ContourPlot[w,
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10},
 ContourShading -> False,
 Contours -> {0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 10.0, 30.0, 50.0, 70.0, 90.0}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I then tried essentially the same function replacing it with the interpolated functions.

```
we = 141.20^2/(16*Pi)*(Abs[e0[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]^2 + 
     Abs[e2[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]^2 + 
     4 Abs[e1[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]^2 Cos[ArcTan[y, x]] + 
     2 Cos[2 ArcTan[y, x]] Re[
       e0[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Conjugate[e2[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]]]);

ContourPlot[we,
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10},
 ContourShading -> False,
 Contours -> {0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 10.0, 30.0, 50.0, 70.0, 90.0}
 ]
```

I was surprised to see that when I used the InterpolationFunction I got some errors.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The CountourPlot did a good job in the middle but had some countours not present in the original plot.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is where I have to stop. I judge the interpolation functions to be 80 percent successful.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you